# Как построить отчёт по кастомным параметрам Firebase Analitics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebaseanalytics

При создании кастомных событий, можно использовать параметры.
Например в стандартном событии level_up, можно указать какой именно уровень пройден.

При просмотре статистики по этому событию, параметры уровня видны только за последние 30 минут (правое окно на скриншоте).

Вопрос: как построить полноценный отчёт по этому событию, что бы были видны параметры.
Построить отчёт по базовому событию level_up можно прям в аналитике (взять период даты, или фильтра аудитории), но это будет суммарное количество всех level_up. И параметры (названия отдельных уровней не видны). Как построить отчёт что бы увидеть за нужный период именно параметры этого события, а не только в за последние 30 минут в автоматическом отчёте реального времени.

```
  string level_name = "level_XX";

  Parameter[] LevelUpParameters = {
      new Parameter(FirebaseAnalytics.ParameterLevel, level_name),
    };
    FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.EventLevelUp, LevelUpParameters);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]